# Undefined class readonly property in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-8.1

I'm using PhpStorm 2020.3 version and error undefined class 'readonly' property in PHP 8.1 new.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

> I used phpstorm 2020.3 version

You need to upgrade your PhpStorm.

The support for PHP 8.1 features has been added in **PhpStorm 2021.3 version**.

See "What’s New in PhpStorm 2021.3" on JetBrains website: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2021-3/#php-81

> **Readonly properties**
>
> PhpStorm 2021.3 will help you make use of readonly properties in your code and make sure they are used correctly.